# How can create 2 buttons on share panel on android? etc: Instagram feed, Instagram chat

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, share

[image]

androidManifest.xml like this,I couldn't create two or more buttons. only one appears

```
 <intent-filter android:label = "@string/share_stories_label">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label = "@string/share_image_label">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.